# Google Interactive Charts with images as custom html tooltip

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Okay so I'm really new at this, so please bear with me. I'm trying to create a Google interactive line chart with custom HTML tooltips that are images from other sources around the web. But I can't get this to work; it won't even show up. This is what I have so far (guided by developers.google.com):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi">    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Visualization API and the chart package.
      google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table, 
      // instantiates the chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      function drawChart() {

      // Create the data table.
      var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      dataTable.addColumn('string', 'Date');
      dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
      dataTable.addColumn({'type': 'string', 'role': 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}});
      dataTable.addRows([
        ['January 1, 2015', 3, '<img width=100px src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/28/Flag_of_the_USA.svg">'],
        ['January 2, 2015', 2, '<img width=100px src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/28/Flag_of_the_USA.svg">'],
        ['January 3, 2015', 5, '<img width=100px src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/28/Flag_of_the_USA.svg">'], 
        ['January 4, 2015', 4, '<img width=100px src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/28/Flag_of_the_USA.svg">'],
        ['January 5, 2015', 2, '<img width=100px src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/28/Flag_of_the_USA.svg">']
      ]);

      // Set chart options
      var options = {
                     tooltip. {isHtml: true},
                     focusTarget: 'category',
                     'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate',
                     'width':900,
                     'height':400,
                     legend: { position: 'bottom' }
    };

      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      var chart = new   google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(dataTable, options);
    }
    </script>
  </head>
```

I know I'm probably doing something completely wrong. I would appreciate someone's help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is an error:

```
 tooltip. {isHtml: true}
```

should be:

```
 tooltip: {isHtml: true}
```

If that doesn't fix the issue, also try moving your callback into the load:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {"callback" : drawChart, 'packages': ["corechart"]});
//google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```